# aws lambda function to support secret manager rotation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

I have created a lambda function which I intend to serve as a secret rotation function to be used by the secrets manager, but when I try to add this function as a rotation function in the secrets manager I get the error **"Secrets Manager cannot invoke the specified lambda function. Ensure that the function policy grants access to the principal secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"**
**but I have already allowed secrets manager to invoke the function in the functions resource based policy**, this is what I have defined

```
{   
 "Version": "2012-10-17",   
 "Id": "default",   
 "Statement": [
     {
       "Sid": "Secret-Manager-Access-To-fun_SSH-function",
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Principal": {
         "Service": "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"
       },
       "Action": "lambda:Invoke",
       "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:296808031351:function:fun_ssh"
     }   
  ] 
}
```

I am unable to understand what I am missing, how do I get this to work?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reason could be that you use incorrect action: `lambda:Invoke`.

The correct action of invoking lambda function is `lambda:InvokeFunction`.

Comment: Thanks this worked great, I also need to invoke another lambda function from this function will this resource policy work for that to