# AWS Secret Manager Rotation Lambda is timing out on a DB secrets rotation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

To Devs, I am using the AWS Secret Manager to rotate secrets on a test MySql DB. AWS is creating the rotation lambda for the MySql DB I created and I have set up the admin/password to be in sync. I have increased the lambda timeout to 15 minutes but it is still timing out.  AWS is creating an application for the lambda and am not able to see the code; how can I debug this?

I have seen ([aws lambda function to support secret manager rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61556395/aws-lambda-function-to-support-secret-manager-rotation)) but in my case AWS is creating the lambda and appears to have the correct permissions.

Thanks,
Marc

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and noticed [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/troubleshoot_rotation.html#troubleshoot_rotation_timing-out) said it was because there was no internet connectivity. You can solve it by adding a VPC Endpoint or a NAT gateway. After that, I used [this](https://github.com/mihaerzen/lambda-internet-access-checker) repository to test the connectivity and was able to fix the issue.